# SQL server 2012 conditional update on table 1 from a temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables 1  `[dbo].[t_Olympic_Country]` where i have all the county list but population and GDP is empty. Now i have second table which has most of the countries with population and GDP data but its it has not same number of data. I would like to enter value of GDP and population from 2nd temp table `[dbo].[temptable1]` to first `[dbo].[t_Olympic_Country]` in case the cuntry name matches with `[dbo].[t_Olympic_Country]`. I mean a conditional bulk update for `[dbo].[t_Olympic_Country]`.

I tried following which gives error :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t_Olympic_Country](
[GDP]

)
SELECT 
temp.[GDP]
FROM  [dbo].[temptable1] temp
WHERE (temp.[Country_Name] IN (SELECT tl.[Country_Name] FROM [dbo].[t_Olympic_Country] tl)) 
and  temp.Country_Name not like 'Indep. Olympic Participants'
order by temp.[Country_Name]
```

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Country_Id', table 'Olympic.dbo.t_Olympic_Country'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>       The statement has been terminated. asc

Please find my table structure as follows:

**[dbo].[t_Olympic_Country]:**

```
Country_Id  Country_Name    Country_Size    c_population    GDP
1            Afghanistan            Null    Null            NULL
2            Albania                Null    Null            NULL
3            Algeria                Null    Null            NULL
4            American Samoa         Null    Null            NULL
5            Andorra                Null    Null            NULL
```

**[dbo].[temptable1]:**

```
Country_Name    GDP                 c_population
Afghanistan     20038215159.38730   31627506
Albania         13211513725.58810   2894475
Algeria         213518488688.12000  38934334
American Samoa  645000000.00000     55434
Andorra         3249000000.00000    72786
```

Comment: You have two choices, you can either insert a non `NULL` value for the `Country_Id` column, or you can create a new table where `Country_Id` is auto increment.  In this case, inserting `NULL` would be OK because SQL Server would automatically assign an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have "country" in both the tables. so I think you don't need to insert new records just need to update matching record. you can run update query wit JOIN.
Like below query

```
UPDATE c
set c.GDP = t.GDP
From t_Olympic_Country c
JOIN temptable1 t on c.Country_Name= t.Country_Name
```

*Include other WHERE conditions as per your logic*

Answer (score 0):

Yes Many thanks that worked.

```
UPDATE c
set c.[c_population] = t.[c_population]
From t_Olympic_Country c
JOIN temptable1 t on c.Country_Name= t.Country_Name
where  t.Country_Name not like 'Indep. Olympic Participants'
```